# Windows Store App - Unable to insert frame into page

Tags: c#, .net, windows, store

Evening..
I have a problem in my Windows Store App. I have made a blank page, and I want to insert a frame here, lie this:

```
    <Frame HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <local: RegisterPage/> 
    </Frame>
```

But its not working. In my visual studio 2013 it is displayed a big gray frame with a red error icon and the text "Cannot create an instance of RegisterPage". If I add a blank page, its working. This is (obviously) leaving me to think there is something in my RegisterPage that is the issue, but I have no clue what, and honestly I think this error message is very unclear. I will show how my page basically looks, with the removal of properties and duplicate elements.

```
<Page
x:Class="AntiVirusApp.RegisterPage"
SizeChanged="WindowSize"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AntiVirusApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="Black" PointerMoved="MovePointer" PointerReleased="CanvasPointerReleased">
    <Canvas x:Name="ElementCanvas" Width="1080" Height="720">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="Scale" CenterX="540" CenterY="360" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Graphics/Backgrounds/MenuBG.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Canvas.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <ReorderThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Canvas.ChildrenTransitions>
  <!-- Here are also a bunch of textblocks and images-->
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas x:Name="PointerCanvas">
        <Rectangle x:Name="PointerX" Fill="DarkRed" Height="720" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="4" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="PointerY" Fill="DarkRed" Height="4" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="1080" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I can show the stacktrace of the exception/inner exception too, if it is of any help, but it didnt look very pretty, so I skipped it for now.

Anyone have any ideas whats wrong??

Comment: pfff, just found it.. Apparently, its the Canvas.ChildrenTransitions that are messing with me :b

Comment: .. Or well, it worked until I ran my app and now its showing an error again. For the record, I can run my app (with or without the ChildrenTransitions). But its just showing a huge error in my design :p